Red tinted screen after enabling #WaylandEnable=false # AutomaticLoginEnable = true # AutomaticLogin = user1
Red tinted screen after enabling
#WaylandEnable=false 
#AutomaticLoginEnable = true 
#AutomaticLogin = user1 

these options for anydesk to work properly but now the screen has red tint in it.
how to resolve it without disturbing the anydesk functionality.

Providing details of your Ubuntu product & release may help.
